# No change in image rotation using php imagerotate()

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, image-rotation

Ok.. now I have been trying this for long time now.

I am trying to rotate image if it has some orientation .
I got reference from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657023/how-to-detect-shot-angle-of-photo-and-auto-rotate-for-website-display-like-desk)

I also refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474634/imagerotate-doesnt-work)

Here is function I am using

```
function adjustPicOrientation($full_filename){        
$exif = exif_read_data($full_filename);
if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
    $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
    if($orientation != 1){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($full_filename);

        $mirror = false;
        $deg    = 0;

        switch ($orientation) {
          case 2:
            $mirror = true;
            break;
          case 3:
            $deg = 180;
            break;
          case 4:
            $deg = 180;
            $mirror = true;  
            break;
          case 5:
            $deg = 270;
            $mirror = true; 
            break;
          case 6:
            $deg = 270;
            break;
          case 7:
            $deg = 90;
            $mirror = true; 
            break;
          case 8:
            $deg = 90;
            break;
        }
        if ($deg) $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);    
        $full_filename = str_replace('.jpg', "-O$orientation.jpg",  $full_filename); 
        imagejpeg($img, $full_filename, 95);
    }
}
return $full_filename;
}
```

A new image with new name is getting saved but there is no rotation change.

Actually I am facing very unexpected issue .. 
when I rotate image with static rotation angle it is working fine ..
but it is not working for the rotation angles mentioned in conditions ..
I am no able to figure it out ...

Can I body suggest me what went wrong .. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do all parts of code execute properly (like `if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation']))` and `if($orientation != 1){`)?

Comment: @Voitcus yes code is running properly . and coming in proper conditions .. but I am unable to get why I am not getting any rotation

Comment: try to not use same variable for old and new image. it may help to find the problem

Comment: Try what @Phantom suggests and if not, try if `imagerotate` works at all.

Comment: Use `$img2 = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);` and then `imagejpeg($img2, $full_filename, 95);`

Comment: @Voitcus tried but not working .

Comment: use some debug output for your $deg and make sure it is not 0

Comment: You don't use your `$mirror` variable, maybe you test the code using mirrors not rotations.

Comment: Does `imagerotate` work in other cases? Does it return resource?

Comment: Yes it is returning the resource

Comment: well ... try to replace this function body with something simplest (remove all conditions etc.). like this: `$new_img = imagerotate($old_img, 90, 0);` and check the result. if it works -start adding additional lines one by one.

Comment: You may also try if this line really executes `if ($deg) $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);` for example `if($deg){ $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0); echo 'Yes it does';}`

Comment: @Voitcus I tried `var_dump($img)` after `imagerotate($img, $deg, 0)`. it is giving `resource(65, gd)`

Comment: But we don't know if the picture has changed. This might be a problem with your GD library, with the file system (Maybe instead of saving the file output it to the browser to ensure it isn't the file problem), even in your code -- it seems ok, but maybe there is some stupid mistake. If some part of your code doesn't work, YOU are the first suspect, so I want to know this line really runs. Var_dumping will not help in this case, because we cannot compare the image before and after. You can also try other GD function like imageflip, test it if it would work with bitmaps or gifs, etc.